# Google Apps forms Script openById , openByUrl is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have started to learn Google App Scripting and was stuck at the first example using the Forms Api.

Following is my code:

```
function testFunction(){
  var newClientForm = FormApp.openById('1f-676zsIuVpsQVSr1tAxttTs********');

var clientForm = FormApp.openByUrl('Url of the form in edit mode');

Logger.log('The form Title is ', newClientForm.getTitle());
Logger.log('The form Title is ', clientForm.getTitle());
}
```

Either way when I check the logs I only get the string message with blank values.

To check that my form id is correct I have tried deleted new characters in the Id and the script reports an error. But when the correct Id is mentioned the script does not work as expected.

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have spotted my mistake

The issues was with the Logger.log() method which i was incorrectly using. I should have mentioned as

Logger.log('The form Title is %s', newClientForm.getTitle());

I was missing the formatter '%s'